# How do I restore only 1 mySQL value row for an entire table?

Tags: mysql

I have a serious issue with a mySQL database, but luckily I have backups. I just don't know how to restore that affected part without modifying the others.

I have rows with:

```
product | name | country
```

The `product` and `name` should stay as they are, but for each of the rows I have to restore the `country` part as they are in the .sql backup file. What's the easiest way to do that?

Something like

```
`UPDATE my_table SET country="123,123,134" WHERE product="9876"
`UPDATE my_table SET country="482,482,593" WHERE product="4543"
```

etc.

The `country` value is different for each `product`.

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: One thought, I could duplicate the table from backup with the correct records and then restore each one with a `foreach product` maybe with PHP?

Comment: I'd import the backup to another table and then use SQL to update the actual table (of which I'd make a new backup, first).

Comment: `UPDATE my_table INNER JOIN my_table_backup USING (primary_key) SET my_table.country = my_table_backup.country`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume there is a primary key in your table that you just did not mention, so it is actually:

```
my_table
ID | product | name | country
```

Restore the table from your backup under another name, let's say `my_backup_table`. Then use the following SQL:

```
UPDATE my_table SET my_table.country = my_backup_table.country 
WHERE my_table.ID = my_backup_table.ID
```

Comment: That's right, I do have a primary key that is "product_id". Your command makes perfect sense but when I run it, it says "unknown column". I can see the primary key in the old database and the restored one, though!

Comment: The weird thing is when I do a `SELECT product_id FROM my_backup_table` it shows correctly. Wtf..

Comment: Try these two commands and let me know if you get any error: `SELECT product_id, country FROM my_table` and `SELECT product_id, country FROM my_backup_table`. If they both work without error, then this one should work: `UPDATE my_table SET my_table.country = my_backup_table.country 
WHERE my_table.product_id = my_backup_table.product_id`. Make sure you use the correct capitalization of the column name if your MySQL is running on an OS other than Windows.

Comment: You're forgetting the `left join backup_table USING(product_id)`.